# How to add Alt tag for the image in the Teaser component in AEM?

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6, teaser, aem-core-wcm-components

I would like to add the alt tag similar to the image component in the teaser component.

The OOTB teaser component uses data-sly-resource.

```
<sly data-sly-template.image="${@ teaser}">
    <div data-sly-test="${teaser.imageResource}" data-sly-resource="${teaser.imageResource}"></div>
</sly>
```

Can I pass attribute values on data-sly-resource?

```
    <div data-sly-test="${teaser.imageResource}" data-sly-resource="${teaser.imageResource @ alt = properties.alt}"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

AEM 6.5
2.6.0
4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

In the HTL Sling implementation you can pass parameters on `data-sly-resource` (using request attributes - see [SLING-5812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5812)). However, this would require the rendering of the image to be aware of these and use them.

As you seem to be using [AEM WCM Core Components](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components), the image component will try to fetch the data for `alt` attribute from the [`alt` property of the resource](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.day.cq.commons.ImageResource.PN_ALT). You could wrap the resource and provide a custom `alt` property to get around to what you need.